# PHP flush the output to browser

Tags: php, flush

I work on a PHP project and I use `flush()`.

I did a lot of search and found that PHP sends long outputs of scripts to the browser in chunk parts and does not send all the huge data when the script terminates.

I want to know the size of this data, I mean how many bytes the output must be for PHP to send them to browser.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the browser has some kind of limit too, before it decides to actually display it.

Comment: yeh.modern browser must receive 512 byte to display contents but i want to know php limit to auto flush the output to browser(without calling flush() function)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering

Comment: the Description section on the flush() pages has the most information i could find - there is no fixed answer to this.

Comment: no,php dont use it.in my system output_buffering is off but when i run a script with a loop with 100,000 times the script progressively catch data from php that means php send output in chunk parts not script termination..i know what output_buffering=on do but php without this directive send chunk size output on LARGE scripts

Comment: as the manual says it may not be a php issues, there is the browser and server to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not only PHP that chunks the data; it's actually the job of Apache (or Tomcat etc) to do this. That's why the default is to turn off the "chunking" in PHP and leave it to Apache. Even if you force a flush from PHP, it still can get trapped by Apache. From the manual:

> flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web
>   server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the
>   browser. It also doesn't affect PHP's userspace output buffering
>   mechanism. This means you will have to call both ob_flush() and
>   flush() to flush the ob output buffers if you are using those.

There's a Wikipedia article on transfer encoding / chunking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Apache gets more complicated with GZIP or deflate encoding; you'll need to hit an apache server as to how you chan configure it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are wrong
see this code

```
echo str_repeat(' ',1024);
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
echo $i;
flush();
sleep(1);
```

if you run it see that every 1 byte sent to browser and print
//the str_repeat is for browser buffer for showing data and nothing else

Comment: It all depends on your webserver config and browser. Fastest way is to turn on GZIP on your apache and then see what happens.

Comment: it's not even a valid PHP code